# Setting an Array as scope in angularJS not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RMzRB/107/)

```
var myArray = [{firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age:29},
{firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 32}];
```

html

```
<body ng-app="" ng-init="users = myArray">

    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
         {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} - Age: {{user.age}}
    <div>
</body>
```

Here in Fiddle i want to Set MyArray as items in ng-init but its not working.

Comment: your approach is completely wrong...read a little more about angularjs

Comment: I want to Use Same controller on page but i want different arrays each time

Answer (score 0):

Angular has no clue about your array until or unless your link it some how (with model / $scope in controller or int html), see it is working now as i declared it in ng-init

```
  <body ng-app="" 
        ng-init="users = [
   {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age:29}, 
   {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 32}
  ]">

    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
         {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} - Age: {{user.age}}
    <div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to Use Same controller on page but i want different arrays each time

Answer (score 0):

When you write expressions in the HTML (such as `users = myArray`), the variables that you use need to be in the controller's `$scope`. So somewhere you need to pt myArray into your scope, see example below:

```js
angular.module("test", []).controller("test", function($scope) {
  $scope.myArray = [
    {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', age:29},
    {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 32}
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <div ng-init="users = myArray">
    <div ng-repeat="user in users">
      {{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} - Age: {{user.age}}
    <div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that it is unclear why you want that `ng-init`, why don't you simply loop over myArray? `ng-repeat = "user in myArray"`

Comment: I want to Use Same controller on page but i want different arrays each time

Comment: So just write `$scope.myArray = myArray` from whatever array you want. The thing is you need to put an array in the scope anyway at some point

Comment: Thanks worked for me,,I did some modification but thanks for tip

Comment: Glad to hear. Be sure to upvote and accept the answer if that helped you so it can help other people, thanks :)